# Grouping filter queries in Booking.com clone

Tags: postgresql

We are developing a product comparison website with filters for product properties, similar to Booking.com, Copart.com etc.
These filters include the resulting product count in case the property of the filter is applied (e.g. under the *Brand* filter, checkboxes with brand names and the amount of resulting products if this checkbox would be clicked for each brand).
To obtain the information for a filter, a unique query per filter is executed, including the clauses from all other filters, but excluding the clauses for the current filter properties).

While the individual queries are reasonably fast (about 60ms/query) and can be executed concurrently, this approach does not scale well as the number of filters increases, since the database has 100% resource utilization processing a single query at a time.

How can this problem be mitigated to make everything fast and scalable?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! You're going to have to supply a **lot** more information with your question! What is your current scenario? What are your table definitions? **Indexes**? Provide a fiddle (dbfiddle.uk) and some estimates as to your tables' cardinality. Also, what is your H/ware  like? 60ms per query is very easy if you have 20 records/table...